# Unzipping file and uploading to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, etl

The route on node takes a zip file and from there I unzip it into memory and upload it to S3 bucket. Everything is working fine, but I am struggling with resolving after all files from the zip file are done.

```
function unzipAndUploadToS3(fileInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(fileInfo.zip.path)
            .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
            .pipe(etl.map(entry => {
                if (checkEntry(entry.path)) {
                    fileInfo.name = entry.path;
                    entry
                        .buffer()
                        .then(content => {
                            fileInfo.data = content;
                            AWS.uploadToS3(fileInfo).then(result => {
                                console.log(result.Location);
                                resolve(result.Location);  //ALWAYS Resolves here
                            }).catch(err => {
                                console.error(err);
                                reject(err);
                            })
                        })
                }
                else
                    entry.autodrain();
            }))
    });
}
```

I've tried a Promise.all and Async/Await, but can seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `etl` before, but their [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/etl) has a comment that says

> Switch from stream to promise chain ...

And then gives the code `.promise().then(...)`. You say that you tried a `Promise.all`, but you don't say how, so I don't know if you've already tried this. But this is the direction I would think things might go:

```
function unzipAndUploadToS3(fileInfo) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(fileInfo.zip.path)
      .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
      .pipe(etl.map(entry => {
        if (checkEntry(entry.path)) {
          fileInfo.name = entry.path;
          return entry.buffer() //<- return promise
            .then(content => {
              fileInfo.data = content;
              return AWS.uploadToS3(fileInfo) //<- return promise
            })
        }
        else
          entry.autodrain();
      }))
      .promise().then(awsPromises => Promise.all(awsPromises)) //<- return promise
      .then(x => resolve('x should be an array of s3 results'))
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
}
```

For this to work though all the promises need to be properly linked together for the entry buffering and then upload to s3. I marked the important returns to keep the linking with comments.

Also something else that looks a little off to me: I can't believe you're able to keep reusing the same `fileInfo` with multiple files like this. Looks like a race condition to me: will the previous upload finish before the next file overwrites the `fileInfo.data` and `fileInfo.name`? My guess is you'd be better off creating a new fileInfo object inside of your map, instead of reusing the same one for all the files in the zip.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work that way. Perhaps there is something about an async call in a pipe. I've published worked for me below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working for me. This uses unzipper, etl and lodash.

```
function unzipAndUploadToS3(fileInfo) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var filesToProcess = [];
        var filesStream = fs.createReadStream(fileInfo.zip.path)
            .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
            .pipe(etl.map(entry => {
                if (checkEntry(entry.path)) {
                    fileInfo.name = entry.path.substr(entry.path.indexOf('/') + 1, entry.path.length);
                    entry
                        .buffer()
                        .then(content => {
                            fileInfo.data = content;
                            var newObj = _.clone(fileInfo);  //need to clone object because of object reference in assignment
                            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  //create new promise to upload to S3
                                AWS.uploadToS3(newObj).then(result => { //a function in another module uses aws-sdk
                                    resolve(result)
                                }).catch(err => reject(err));
                            })
                            filesToProcess.push(promise);  //push this promise into an array of promises
                        })
                }
                else
                    entry.autodrain();
            }))
        filesStream.on('readable',  function () { console.log('readable');  })
            .on('data',  function (data) { console.log('data', data);  })
            .on('error', function (err)  {
                console.error('Error', err);
                reject(err);
            })
            .on('end',   function ()     {
                Promise.all(filesToProcess).then(values => {    //process all the promises
                    console.log("values>", values);
                    resolve(values);
                }).catch(err => {reject(err)});
            })
    });
}
```